# gwt panel horizontal alignment not working

Tags: gwt, dialog, alignment, panel

I have a GWT dialog box that looks like the following:

```
public class FooDialog extends DialogBox {

public FooDialog() {
        setText("Foo Dialog");
        VerticalPanel outer = new VerticalPanel();
        outer.setBorderWidth(3);
        outer.setSize("400px", "200px");
        outer.setHorizontalAlignment(HasAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
        outer.setVerticalAlignment(HasAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel", new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        hide();
      }
    });

        HorizontalPanel buttons = new HorizontalPanel();
        buttons.setBorderWidth(3);
        buttons.add(cancelButton);

        outer.add(buttons);

        setWidget(outer);
    }
}
```

For some reason the 'buttons' panel does not obey the horizontalAlignment setting; it sticks to the left side of the outer panel. It does, however, obey the vertialAlignment setting. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The alignment works in GWT 1.7.1, hosted mode browser and compiled in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables don't respect the parent's horizontal alignment property. Instead, set the left & right margins of the child table to "auto".

buttons.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("marginLeft", "auto");
buttons.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("marginRight", "auto");

More Info: [Center a table with CSS](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/)

Comment: Thanks Matt! And what if i wanted to align the elements in buttons to the right?

Comment: Nice, thanks Mat.  Setting margins to 'auto' works for a table inside an ASP.NET Panel control as well.